# Cannot access specific website from my arch desktop

Tags: domain-name-system

There is a specific website `www.balaye.net` that I cannot reach from my arch desktop when the rest of the internet works with no problem.

I have tried to use two differents WiFi networks with no success.
Moreover, I can reach the url from other devices running Windows or android.

Here is my config but I am not sure what I need to provide:

File: `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.214.185
```

When using `nslookup www.balaye.net`

```
Server:         192.168.214.185
Address:        192.168.214.185#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.balaye.net  canonical name = https://pietrodito.github.io.
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 185.199.111.153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 185.199.108.153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 185.199.110.153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 185.199.109.153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 2606:50c0:8001::153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 2606:50c0:8000::153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 2606:50c0:8003::153
Name:   https://pietrodito.github.io
Address: 2606:50c0:8002::153
```

When using `dig www.balaye.net`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.4 <<>> www.balaye.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29574
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.balaye.net.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.balaye.net.         159     IN      CNAME   https://pietrodito.github.io.
https://pietrodito.github.io. 159 IN    A       185.199.110.153
https://pietrodito.github.io. 159 IN    A       185.199.109.153
https://pietrodito.github.io. 159 IN    A       185.199.111.153
https://pietrodito.github.io. 159 IN    A       185.199.108.153

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.214.185#53(192.168.214.185) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 08 16:19:31 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138
```

I have tried also this `wget https://www.balaye.net`:

```
--2022-07-08 19:19:53--  https://www.balaye.net/
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving www.balaye.net (www.balaye.net)... failed: Success.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.balaye.net’
```

And when trying to `ping www.balaye.net`:

```
ping: www.balaye.net: System error
```

And when trying `ping www.google.com`:

```
ING www.google.com (216.58.214.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par10s42-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.214.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=53.7 ms
64 bytes from par10s42-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.214.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from par10s42-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.214.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=58.4 ms
64 bytes from par10s42-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.214.164): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=60.6 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.585/55.077/60.585/4.986 ms
```

Comment: Which browser did you use?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Firefox and Chrome

Comment: try to access the site with `wget https://www.balaye.net` (for test)

Comment: Idem. I have edited the question with the result of wget.

Comment: Try to replace your nameserver with 9.9.9.9

Comment: `www.balaye.net. 159 IN CNAME https://pietrodito.github.io.` is a bit bizarre. Shouldn't have the `https://` in there at all. I'm surprised it works at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz It is not a bit bizarre, but completely wrong. CNAME maps a name to a name. URLs have no place in the DNS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek According to github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) I think ceejayoyz is pointing in the right direction. I cite "if you want to use the subdomain `www.example.com` for your user site, create a CNAME record that points www.example.com to `<user>.github.io`". And now it works!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Agreed; what's bizarre is that IPs came back. Checked it on my local machine at the time and I got the IPs, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz "what's bizarre is that IPs came back. " No, not bizarre at all :-) `*.github.io` exists, so it is a wildcard, so `https://pietrodito.github.io.` matches it. Yes, because, in general, CNAME are domain names, not hostnames. domain names can have any characters, so `https://pietrodito` is a valid first label that matches the `*` in the wildcard :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting this to an answer:

```
www.balaye.net. 159 IN CNAME https://pietrodito.github.io.
```

is not a valid CNAME; the `https://` should not be there. Hostname only, no scheme, ports, paths, etc.